# MAGENTO - How to display the category details for editing?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

**Categories**

[image]

I want to update categories in Magento but the problem is when I click to sub-category (Desktops) the details of that category doesn't show up in the "General Infomation" form.

**General Infomation** -- doesn't display the details of selected category
[image]

Also, the number of products in other categories displays zero (0) but there's data exist when you collapsed one of the sub-category.

---

In **System > Index Management**: I didn't do "Reindex Data" action

In **System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend (section)**: 
My **Use Flat Catalog Category**,**Use Flat Catalog Product** is set to `No`

Should I reindex data and set both flat catalog to `yes`? To solve my problem?

---

P.S The front-end is working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reindexing the category products in System → Index management as you suggested. If that doesn't work try flushing Cache Storage under System → Cache Management